# What is the dimension over $ \mathbb{C} $ of $ \mathbb{C} [X,Y] / ( Y^2 - X^2 , Y^2 + X^2 ) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, field-theory

Can you show me how to compute : $ \mathrm{dim}_{ \mathbb{C} } \big( \mathbb{C} [X,Y] / ( Y^2 - X^2 , Y^2 + X^2 ) \big) $ ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly in the quotient ring $Y^2=0=X^2$. The quotient ring is generated as a complex vector space by all monomials in $X$ and $Y$; with the above fact it is clear now that $1,X,Y,XY$ will form a basis, and so the dimension is $4$.

Comment: Maybe one should point out that $(Y^2-X^2,Y^2+X^2)=(Y^2,X^2)$.

Comment: Yes. These two sets have the same linear span, and hence they generate the same ideal.